# How to use function prototype on Leetcode to add a new node at the begining of linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm recreating Linked List in C following [this problem](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/linked-list/209/singly-linked-list/1290/) on Leetcode.
I am at the step of **adding a new node at the head of the list**.
Because the instruction is:

```
/**
 * Your MyLinkedList struct will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyLinkedList* obj = myLinkedListCreate();

 * myLinkedListAddAtHead(obj, val);
**/
```

So I figure out the main should be something like this: (we ignore Memory leaks at the moment).

```
int main(void)
{
    MyLinkedList *head;

    head = myLinkedListCreate();
    myLinkedListAddAtHead(&head, 10);
    myLinkedListAddAtHead(&head, 9);
    myLinkedListAddAtHead(&head, 8);
    return (0);
}
```

I came up with this solutions using pointer to pointer:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MyLinkedList_s
{
    int data;
    struct MyLinkedList_s *next;
} MyLinkedList;

MyLinkedList* create() 
{
    MyLinkedList *node;

    node = (MyLinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(MyLinkedList));
    if (!node)
        return (NULL);
    node = NULL;
    return (node);
}

void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList **obj, int val) 
{
    MyLinkedList *tmp;

    tmp = (MyLinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(MyLinkedList));
    if (!tmp)
        return ;
    tmp->data = val;
    tmp->next = *obj;
    *obj = tmp;
}
```

But the problem is I need to comply with the function prototype: `void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList* obj, int val)`, which uses just a pointer `MyLinkedList* obj`.
If I don't use pointer to pointer, I need to return a pointer, instead of `void` as in the prototype. Something like this:

```
MyLinkedList *myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList *obj, int val) 
{
    MyLinkedList *tmp;

    tmp = (MyLinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(MyLinkedList));
    if (!tmp)
        return ;
    tmp->data = val;
    tmp->next = obj;
    obj = tmp;
    return (obj);
}

int main(void)
{
    MyLinkedList *head;

    head = create();
    head = myLinkedListAddAtHead(head, 10);
    head = myLinkedListAddAtHead(head, 9);
    head = myLinkedListAddAtHead(head, 8);
    return (0);
}
```

The question is, either way I did before, it does not comply with the function prototype. How can I add a new node to the linked list using this: `void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList* obj, int val)`, knowing that `MyLinkedList *head` is created at main.c:

```
int main(void)
{
    MyLinkedList *head;

    head = create();
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is to have a list to not just be a node. For example you could use

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct MyLinkedList {
    struct Node *head;
    /* and optionaly depending on requirements:
    struct Node *tail;
    int nb; */
};
```

Then it becomes trivial:

```
struct MyLinkedList * myLinkedListCreate() {
    MyLinkedList *obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
    obj->head = NULL;
}

void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList *obj, int val) 
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->val = val;
    node->next = obj->head;
    obj->head = node;
}
```